# winapi - Clear a region of a CBitmap

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a 32 bit `CBitmap` buffer on which I `AlphaBlend` things. However I was wondering if there was a way to 'clear' a rectangular region of the CBitmap completely (as in either set all the Alpha values of the pixels in a specific region to 0 or just clear the region completely).

I can't used GDI+!

Comment: Do you mean something different from [`FillRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162719.aspx) or [`Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162898.aspx)? If so, it would probably help to know more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I need something with Alpha blending capabilities, so I can clear the Rectangle

Comment: Use the `<gdiplus.h>` Bitmap class instead.  You can create a Graphics instance with Graphics::FromImage() and draw into the bitmap with 32-bit colors that include an alpha channel.

Comment: Ah yes! I forgot to say I can't use GDI+ either. Will update question

Comment: @Hans Passant could I use FillRect with a GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH) ? would that work?

Comment: GDI doesn't know anything about alpha.  "Can't use GDI+" is something that belongs in a homework question.

Comment: This isn't homework but thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "Clearing" a bitmap. You just change the color of pixels. If you define "clear" as pure black, then you set the pixels to black. The simplest way to do this is with [`CDC::FillRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0421fewx.aspx).

Comment: Sure, but will set set the alpha value?

Comment: FillRect will overwrite the pixels; there is no blending performed. The resulting pixels will be exactly as they are in the brush.

Comment: But what will FillRect overwrite the alpha value of those pixels with? just 0?